# How shall I understand the output `<class 'yyy'>` to a type's name `xxx` in Python interpreter?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python interpreter, when I type in a type's name `xxx`, I get output like `<class 'yyy'>`, where `yyy` and `xxx` are not the same. See the following examples.

I wonder why `yyy` and `xxx` are different, and what they mean respectively? Thanks.

```
>>> builtins.staticmethod
<class 'staticmethod'>

>>> types.MethodType
<class 'method'>
>>> types.FunctionType
<class 'function'>
>>> types.BuiltinFunctionType
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> types.BuiltinMethodType
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>


>>> class C:
...     pass
... 
>>> C
<class '__main__.C'>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, all types are objects.

And you can apply `str` to them. The result of applying `str` to a type object is just some string. For instance:

```
>>> str(type(8))
"<class 'int'>"
>>> str(type(abs))
"<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>"
>>> str(type(lambda x: x + 1))
"<class 'function'>"
>>> str(type((1,2,3)))
"<class 'tuple'>"
>>> str(type(90.4))
"<class 'float'>"
```

Whoever designed a type gets to implement `str` however they want. Now most of these follow a particular pattern, as you can tell in your `C` example.

Now, and here's the cool part, because types are objects, they can be assigned to variables. And *the variable to which they are assigned doesn't have to have anything to do with the type name seen when applying `str`*. It just so happens for example, that the integer type was assigned to the variable `int` within the `builtins` module. Here are a few examples:

```
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.int
<class 'int'>
>>> int
<class 'int'>
>>> float
<class 'float'>
>>> complex
<class 'complex'>
>>> list
<class 'list'>
>>> import types
>>> types.FunctionType
<class 'function'>
>>> types.FunctionType == type(lambda x: x + 1)
True
```

I can even do this

```
>>> integer = float
>>> type(3.2) == integer
True
```

But don't.

TL;DR: One is the variable the type is assigned to, the other is the output of applying `str`. There is no rule saying that have to be the same. When they differ, you have to ask the type's designer.

As to how they can be related, in general they cannot. But most of the builtins are named the same as their string output, and the types in the `types` module seem to have capitalized CamelCase names. User-defined types have the package name prefixed to the class name. I'm not sure this rule is required to be followed in all cases.